# Blazor validation against 'parent field'

Tags: c#, blazor

In my form I have:

```
<BSLabel IsColumn="true">Pallets</BSLabel>
<BSCol ColumnSmall="4">
    <BSInput InputType="InputType.Number" @bind-Value="Booking.PalletsQty"></BSInput>
</BSCol>
<div class="col">
    <BSLabel Class="row">Weight In Kilograms</BSLabel>
    <BSLabel Class="row">(Gross weight of PO)</BSLabel>
</div>
<BSCol ColumnSmall="4">
    <BSInput InputType="InputType.Text" @bind-Value="Booking.Weight"></BSInput>
    <ValidationMessage For="() => Booking.Weight"></ValidationMessage>
</BSCol>
```

What I want to be able to do is if the user enters a pallet qty, then they must enter a weight, so as soon as a value is entered for a pallet qty I want to set the validation message for the weight to say that a weight must be entered, how can I go about this?

Based on Tiny Wang comment, I changed the first input to be:

```
<BSInput InputType="InputType.Number" @bind-Value="Booking.PalletsQty" @onchange="(() => SetBooking())"></BSInput>
```

The method gets called each time I change the value, but the value on the model does not get updated.

Comment: write onchange event to monitor Booking.PalletsQty value and add a label to show the validation data？

Comment: You're supposed to use `OnValueChange="((int x)=>HandleValueChange(x))"` and define an `EditContext _editContext` field which you attach to the BSForm and call the _editContext.Validate() method in the change handler , however I couldn't get the BSForm's `EditContext` to attach to the local field. I would reccomend just creating your own EditForm component and using bootstrap styles.